# Trouble getting PostCSS to work with Webpack

Tags: webpack, postcss, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get Webpack to work with PostCSS and am running into trouble. It minifies JavaScript just fine, but doesn't do anything with the CSS. I've tried a variety of configurations based on examples, but can't get it to work.

The main reason I'm doing this is to get PostCSS to make TailwindCSS work on build instead of having to run the CLI command.

Webpack Config:

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.ts',
    vendor: ['./angular']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader"
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "src/styles.css",
      chunkFilename: "src/css/main.css"
    })
  ]
}
```

PostCSS Config:

```
var tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
      tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
};
```

Package.json

```
{
"name": "ateamcoders-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
"server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
"start": "npm run server",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
"@babel/core": "7.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"eslint": "5.10.0",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"ts-loader": "5.3.1",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"autoprefixer": "9.4.2",
"babel-loader": "8.0.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"cross-env": "5.2.0",
"css-loader": "2.0.0",
"enhanced-resolve": "4.1.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~3.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
"postcss": "7.0.6",
"postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"tailwindcss": "0.7.2",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.1.6",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
"webpack": "4.27.1",
"webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.10"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently stepping away from this let me think outside the box a bit. I looked at what [Coding-Coach](https://github.com/Coding-Coach/coding-coach) was doing to run Tailwind, and they aren't even using Webpack. So, I mirrored their approach. I installed `postcss-cli` and `npm-run-all` with `npm i --save postcss-cli npm-run-all`

Then I modified my `package.json` to look like this:

```
"watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:js watch:css",
"watch:js": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
"watch:css": "postcss src/styles.css -o src/css/main.css -w",
```

Then I can "npm run watch" and it minifies the JS via Webpack and does the Tailwind stuff using the postcss-cli.